How to add a scrollbar to python plotly long title
I am using python plotly to create scatterplot using following function-
def show_products(products: list[ProductInfo], title: str) -> None:
    layout = go.Layout(
                            autosize=False,
                            width=1500,
                            height=1500,
                            xaxis=go.layout.XAxis(linecolor="black", linewidth=5, mirror=True),
                            yaxis=go.layout.YAxis(linecolor="black", linewidth=5, mirror=True),
                            margin=go.layout.Margin(l=50, r=50, b=100, t=100, pad=4),
                        )
    fig = go.Figure(layout=layout)

    for product in products:
        add_scatter_plot(
            fig,
            product,
            name_format="%website - %name - %id",
        )
    title_=dict(
                      text=title,
                      x=0.5,
                      y=.97,
                      xanchor='center',
                      yanchor='top',
                      pad = dict(
                                 t = -10
                                ),
                      font=dict(
                          #family='Courier New, monospace',
                          size=12,
                          color='#000000'
                      )
                )
    config_figure(fig, title_)

But the problem is the title of my scatterplot is long(500 character+) so tried another trick to add <br /> after some portion of the title. But all went in vain. How can I add horizontal scrollbar to accommodate long title?
Without adding <br /> tag, some of the part of title is out of view-

After adding <br /> tag, title overlaps the chart area-


does it solve your problem?
<div style="width: 400px; overflow-x: auto; white-space: nowrap;">This is a very very very very very very very very very very very very very long title that needs scrolling</div>

@Arash No... It just adds html codes( like<div style="width: 400px; overflow-x: auto; white-space: nowrap;">B0BTQWR77M,B0CJS18VMV......</div> ) but does not render.

maybe it needs to use JavaScript or CSS directly in HTML: Adding CSS & JS and Overriding the Page-Load Template | Dash for Python Documentation | Plotly

@furas It needs dash ,another library, then.

you didn't create minimal working code so we have to guess what you use. And we can't test ideas with CSS. Maybe you need only information about CSS without dash
